# Understanding geolocation on tweets

Tags: php, javascript, geolocation, twitter

I'm trying to get geolocation from tweets.
For my tests, I posted new tweets geo-referenced but when I got the json of them, the element 'geo' is null. Why? What's wrong with them?

I don't want to search by range and geolocation: I want to search some tweets indexed by a particular hashtag and then retrieve 'geo' json element.
I tried to search other tweets (not mine) and sometimes I got 'geo' element as a full object, with coordinates array.

**So, what can I do to have 'geo' element not null?**

I did 4 posts geo-referenced: [my tweets](https://twitter.com/#!/wilkyx)

The location is: 44.694704,10.528611

Edit: Added geocode param

This is what I've done server-side (pure php):

```
$conn = new OAuth (CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET);
$conn->setToken (ACCESS_TOKEN, ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET);
$conn->fetch (API_URL, array ('q' => '#testhashtagandgeo', 'geocode' => '44.694704,10.528611,4km'));
echo $conn->getLastResponse ();
```

I used PHP OAuth base and each constant is defined correctly, so it works good.

Client-side (ExtJS):

```
Ext.onReady (function () {
    Ext.Ajax.request ({
        url: 'proxy.php' ,
        disableCaching: false ,
        success: function (xhr) {
            var js = Ext.JSON.decode (xhr.responseText);
            Ext.each (js.results, function (tweet) {
                if (tweet.geo !== null) {
                    console.log ('lat = ' + tweet.geo.coordinates[0] + ' - lng = ' + tweet.geo.coordinates[1]);
                }
            });
            console.log (js);
        } ,
        failure: function (xhr) {
            console.log ('something\'s wrong!');
        }
    });
});
```

Thanks in advance.

Wilk

Answer (score 0):

You need to [read the documentation](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/using-search)

> Location data is only included if the query includes the geocode parameter, and the user Tweeted with Geo information.

So, you need to add something like this to your query

```
&geocode=37.781157,-122.398720,25mi
```

Or whichever location you want.

Comment: So, it's impossible to query twetter without geocode into the query?

Comment: That's right. You need to give it a geocode in order to get back geoencoded information. There are two ways round this
1) Get the individual tweet IDs and query them from the main API.
2) Put in a location and a sufficiently high radius to catch all your users.

Comment: Very well. I just edited my question: I added geocode param and my twitter homepage. As you can see, there are 4 posts geolocated at the coords I've reported. However, it doens't work yet. I got no posts with that hashtag (#testhashtagandgeo) and with those coords (44.694704,10.528611). You can increase the geocode's radius but the result is the same.

Comment: Did you URL Encode your search? Should be %23testhastagandgeo (I don't know if the library you're using does it automagically)

Comment: Yes yes but this is not the problem. My experiments bring me to use Twitter Streaming API instead of REST API. Unfortunately, they are very difficult to implement, so I need more time to understand the right way to do it. Anyway, I discovered that tweets posted  and geo-referenced by mobile have 'geo' tag filled with coordinates.